# php form change sha1 password with sed and exec

Tags: php, forms, passwords, exec, sha1

I'm working on a simple password reset form, thanks to a great deal of help here I have something working. However I would like to add a twist and save the reset password in sha1. Here is my code:

```
#password file
$password='something';

<?php

// Change password

$rawPassword = (isset($_REQUEST["change_pwd"]));
$salt = "lgv932q2e9dshufkdjgf927gf8hlo082";
$newpass = sha1($salt . $rawPassword);


  $change_pass = exec('sed -i " . escapeshellarg("s/\$password=.*/\$password=\'$newpass\'/g")." include/conf.php');

  echo "$change_pass";

?>

<form method="get" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="change_pwd" maxlength="41">
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

When I submit the new password, it doesn't change the sha1 password correctly in the file. Instead every time the password value gets changed to:

```
$password='356a192b7913b04c54574d18c28d46e6395428ab';
```

Update: I salted the password and I'm still getting the same result. (I'm also wondering if there is a better way to do this other than using exec with sed?)

Comment: Shouldn't your form method be POST?

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you punching in the same password to test with each time?  Without a salt in your password you will get the same output result with the same input every time.  I would recommend salting your password to get different output even if using the same input value.

Comment: I'm testing different passwords each time, the result is always the same in the file though. I just tried salting the password and I get a similar result. I'll update my code w/ salt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I have taken a closer look and I found a couple things for your consideration.

First thing I would do is probably use POST for the form method and then capture the data in the $_POST array in PHP.  You also appear to have a variable outside of your PHP tags, which will output as raw text to the browser in the context it is in.

Salting was a good thing to do and will help with making your passwords harder to crack.  Optionally (and recommended) is to generate random salts and attach them to your passwords for added strength, among other benefits.  Just remember to include your salt in the future when hashing the password again during authentication.

The following code should work for you at generating a new password hash, regardless if using the same password.

```
<?php

// Change password
if(isset($_POST["change_pwd"])) {
    $rawPassword = $_POST["change_pwd"]; 
    $salt = sha1(microtime()."lgv932q2e9dshufkdjgf927gf8hlo082");
    $newpass = sha1($salt . $rawPassword).$salt;
}

  $change_pass = exec('sed -i ' . escapeshellarg("s/\$password=.*/\$password=\'$newpass\'/g"). ' include/conf.php');
  //Also helpful to note that PHP halts execution until the command in exec() completes

  echo "$newpass";

?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="change_pwd" maxlength="41">
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Hope that helps you out!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that gives me plenty to chew on. I did try your code and it did appear to generate a password on the page itself, however the include/conf.php file appears to be unchanged by the script.

Comment: I made an edit to the exec() command.  The command string itself is enclosed in single quotes but double quotes were being used before the concatenation operator.  Therefore the output from the escapeshellarg() function wasn't being concatenated to the sed command and instead it was part of the string being sent to sed, likely resulting in an error.  I wish I could say more, it has been a long time since I played with Linux so I can't say anything about the syntactical correctness of your sed command.

Comment: It works like a charm, thanks again. Now  need to spend sometime understanding what exactly you did :)